# Can four (4) single VertexBuffers be associated to each fields of a Vertex Attribute register?

Tags: field, allocation, vertex-buffer, stage3d, agal

In `Stage3D` / `AGAL`, is it possible to point for individual VertexBuffers to the same `va0` in such a way so that:

- Each `VertexBuffer` data can be independently changed (would assume this is great performance in some situations, yes?).
- Each `VertexBuffer` focuses on one field of the `va0` (first vertex-attribute register), so that vertexbuffer1 manipulates `va0.x`, vertexbuffer2 = `va0.y`, vertexbuffer3 = `va0.z`, and vertexbuffer4 = `va0.w`;

Since you can specify the 'offset' and the data format (ex: FLOAT_1, FLOAT_4) when assigning a VertexBuffer to the `Context3D` object, I would imagine this could be possible.

Maybe my setup is incorrect, but when I tried this I couldn't achieve it.

Does each VertexBuffer need to take up the entire 4 fields in each register? If so, I'm not sure I understand why the FLOAT_1 -to- FLOAT_3 values exists! :S

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I found the solution to this while looking at the source code for Axel (axgl.org). I'll post an elaborate answer later on, but for now - it looks like `VertexBuffer`s can be reused at different vertex-attribute registers, and playing with the offset can yield some neat solutions when using FLOAT_2. Doesn't look like separate VertexBuffers can be assigned to the same vertex-attribute without overwriting the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign vertex buffer, or constant, you allocate 128 bit (i.e. 4 x 32). And you will be bounded exactly to one attribute (va0, va1). So I think it's impossible to bound different buffers to single attribute. And if you put FLOAT_1, you will waste memory.